# Importing a TIFF to GeoServer

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I am working to upload a TIFF file into GeoServer so that it can be viewed in layer preview. I exported the TIFF from DroneDeploy, it has an associated geographic location. I was not able to get the GeoTIFF Store to recognize the URL of my file...kept getting errors. I tried using the raster2pgsql extension to upload into pgAdmin and then use a PostGIS store. I was able to upload, however, I get an error in layer preview, "Error rendering coverage on the fast path java.lang.NullPointerException"

I am semi-new to the open-source GIS world.

Comment: are you loading a GeoTiff or a PostGIS raster? these are two different processes

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.